# The space of bounded continuous functions on the real line is not separable

Tags: functional-analysis

> Prove that the space $C(\mathbb R)$ of all continuous functions on $\mathbb R$, equipped with the sup-metric: $$\mathrm d(x, y) := \sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\vert x(t) - y(t)\vert$$ is not separable.
>
> Hint: You may wish to consider the set $$\Lambda := \lbrace f\in C(\mathbb R)\,\vert\,f(n) = n\,\text{or}\,f(n) = 0\,\forall n\in\mathbb N\rbrace.$$

I need help with this question. No clue how to do.

Comment: $d$ is not metric on this space. A metric can not take the value $\infty$

Comment: Presumably you meant "bounded continuous functions"?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to restrict the space $C(\mathbb R)$ to the space of all bounded continuous functions you can instead consider the metric $d(f,g)=\sup\{|f(x-g(x)|\wedge 1: x\in\mathbb R\}$, where $a\wedge b=\min\{a,b\}$. For any two different functions in $\Gamma=\{f\in C(\mathbb R): f(n)\in \{0,1\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N\}$ you then have $d(f,g)=1$. Moreover, $\Gamma$ is uncountable (essentially, because $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is uncountable), and therefore, $C(\mathbb R)$ is not separable: If $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense, then $\Gamma\to \mathbb N$, $f\mapsto \min\{n\in\mathbb N: d(f,f_n)< 1/2\}$ would be injective.

Comment: Nice solution that addresses omission in question.